# Swipe Page View Controller and update page number

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` in my program. I have added a `UITextView` programmatically at the top of `UIPageViewController`.I want to update the text of `UITextView` with each swipe to page `1` of `n` or  `2` of `n` or ….

How should I update the `TextView` to have the correct image number? Where should I call `updateStatusLabelText` function?

The reason why I used `UITextView` is that I could not add a `UILabel` with constraints through code to the top of `UIPageViewController`.

First class is as follows:

```
class MainPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    let dS = MainPageViewControllerDataSource()

    var statusText : String = ""

    var statusTextView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        statusTextView = UITextView(frame: view.bounds)

        statusTextView.text = statusText

        statusTextView.editable = false

        statusTextView.textAlignment = .Center

        statusTextView.font = UIFont(name: statusTextView.font!.fontName, size: 18)

        statusTextView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        view.addSubview(statusTextView)

        view.sendSubviewToBack(statusTextView)

    }

    func updateStatusLabelText(arrayKey:Int){

        statusTextView.text = "\(arrayKey + 1) of \(imageArray.count) "

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        dataSource = dS

        setViewControllers([dS.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as TutorialViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Second class

```
class MainPageViewControllerDataSource: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var tutorialViewControllerDelegate: TutorialViewControllerDelegate?

    var pageIndex = Int()

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TutorialViewController {

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tutorialVC") as! TutorialViewController

        vc.myImage = imageArray[index]

        vc.pageIndex = index

        self.pageIndex = index

        return vc

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! TutorialViewController).pageIndex

        index -= 1

        switch index {

        case Int.min ... (-1):

            return nil

        case NSNotFound:

            fatalError("NSNotFound. Should crash.")

        case imageArray.count..<Int.max:

            return nil

        default:

            return viewControllerAtIndex(index)

        }

    }



    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! TutorialViewController).pageIndex

        index += 1

        switch index {

        case Int.min ... (-1):

            return nil

        case NSNotFound:

            fatalError("NSNotFound. Should crash.")

        case imageArray.count ..< Int.max:

            return nil

        default:

            return viewControllerAtIndex(index)

        }

    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        return imageArray.count

    }


    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        return pageIndex - 1

    }

}
```

Third class:

```
class TutorialViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageToPresent: UIImageView!

    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var myImage : MyImage?

    var pageIndex = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageToPresent = myImage
    }

}
```

Comment: You can directly access the index of the current page from your code.(or like this yourPageControlName.currentPage = "\(set your UILabel here)" so you get the current index of the pageVC. and use swipe gesture leftSwipe to increment index+1 and right swipe to decrement index-1....Hope you can understand the logic....

Comment: I have tried some implementations before.In my implementations some times the page number does not vary correctly and it is almost one step ahead. And also sometimes it responds to incomplete swipes. I'll try yours